# Add class to content field (link) in drupal

Tags: drupal, twig, field, addclass, drupal-8

I want to add a class to the `<a>`-Tag of a Field that consists of a URL-link and a link text (it's a field of type "Link") and the name of the field is `content.field_c_button_link`
So with twig in my HTML-File I want to have something like this:

```
{{ content.field_c_button_link.0.addClass('button blue') }}
```

How can I add a class properly?

Comment: You should try {{ content.field_c_button_link[0].addClass('button blue') }}

Answer (score 4):

Why not piece the anchor tag together manually?  That way you have complete control over everything. Something like this in your template

```
<a href="{{content.field_url.0['#url']}}" class="custom classes">{{content.field_url.0['#title']}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is horrible but it's the only way I found to get this to work:

If you look at the default drupal build array for your link you should see that content.field_c_button_link.0 is an array(4)

```
'#type' => string(4) "link"
'#title' => string(15) "Big Blue Button"
'#options' => array(0)
'#url' => object Drupal\Core\Url(11)
```

So, to set classes directly on the `<a>` tag we have to load '#options' (which is presently empty) with the right setup of subarrays

```
'#options' => array(1)
'attributes' => array(1)
'class' => array(2)
string(6) "button"
string(4) "blue"
```

The only way I could find to do this within twig was to use a series of temps and merging them with the original array because twig wouldn't parse anything else I tried:

```
{% set temp = {'attributes': {'class': ['button','blue']}} %}
{% set temp2 = content.field_c_button_link.0 %}
{% set temp2 = temp2|merge({'#options': temp}) %}
{% set temp3 = content.field_c_button_link|without('0')  %}
{% set temp3 = temp3|merge({'0': temp2}) %}
{% set content = content|merge({'field_c_button_link': temp3}) %}
```

Note the |without which is a Drupal/twig filter.  I had to use it to remove the empty '0' element to avoid having the link print twice.

Please tell me there is an easier way.